# I need to find latitudes and longitudes for companies that have a value of 0 based on zip code in Microsoft Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master-sheet with all of the zip codes and the corresponding latitudes and longitudes for each zip code.

║  B ║  C  ║ D ║

║  20812 ║ 38.96837 ║ -77.14141 ║

║  20813 ║ 38.96451 ║  -77.08789 ║

║  20814 ║ 39.00824 ║  -77.0976 ║

║  20815 ║ 38.98761 ║  -77.06796 ║

---

But the pasteSheet already contains some values, prefilled.

║  D ║  E  ║ F ║

║  20812 ║ 38.96837 ║ -77.14141 ║

║  20813 ║ 0 ║  0 ║

║  20814 ║ 39.00824 ║  -77.0976 ║

║  20815 ║ 0 ║  0 ║

The PasteSheet already has data about Zip lat and long.
But in some locations of lat and long, 0 is already present.

---

Code needed to implement to replace:

1. Iterate through the PasteSheet and find 0.
2. When a 0 is encountered, compare the zip from pastesheet to the zip in the mastersheet
3. if match found copy the values of lat and long from master to pastesheet
4. else leave it as it is.

The PasteSheet is where I need to paste latitudes and longitudes when 0 is encountered.

---

Just to let you know, I don't have a whole lot of programming experience and I have not used VBA before, so this is my first time writing code in VBA.

So far this is the code I've come up with:

```
Sub LatLong()

Dim lat_sh1 As Range
Dim long_sh1 As Range
Dim zip_sh1 As Range
Dim zip_sh2 As Range
Dim lat_sh2 As Range
Dim long_sh2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet
'Set lat_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("E2:E970")'
'Set long_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("F2:F970")'
'Set zip_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("D2:D970")'
'Set zip_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("B1:B99929")'
'Set lat_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("C1:C99929")'
'Set long_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("D1:D99929")'
Set MasterSheet = Sheets(2)
Set PasteSheet = Sheets(1)

For Each cell In PasteSheet.Range("E2:E970")

    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Or cell.Value = 0 Then Exit For

End Sub
```

Comment: I might be missing something.. but why can't you use a VLOOKUP?

Comment: Your code will only work until it finds the first cell that is empty or has a value of 0, because you immediately do an `Exit For` at that point and stop processing any subsequent cells.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up Skram's comment, I'd use a index/match. Following your setup in comments in your code. in Sheet1, where you want the lattitude use this formula in column G (which I'm assuming is currently empty, but will be the new zip code

```
=if(or(D2=0,D2=""),index(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$99929, match(E2&F2,sheet2!$C$2:$C$99929&Sheet2!$D$2:$D$99929,0),1),D2)
```

Ensure to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when you complete the formula, as it will need to be an array, as you have to lookup the combined lat-lon, in a combined lat-lon column. Alternately, create yourself a key column in sheet two column A that does this (eg lat&lon), then you can use a normal vlookup instead of an array index/match.

Alternately, you could do this in VBA, and replace the ZIP code on sheet 1.

```
Sub LatLong()

Dim lat_sh1 As Range
Dim long_sh1 As Range
Dim zip_sh1 As Range
Dim zip_sh2 As Range
Dim lat_sh2 As Range
Dim long_sh2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet
'Set lat_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("E2:E970")'
'Set long_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("F2:F970")'
'Set zip_sh1 = Sheet1.Range("D2:D970")'
'Set zip_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("B1:B99929")'
'Set lat_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("C1:C99929")'
'Set long_sh2 = Sheet2.Range("D1:D99929")'
dim currLat as string
dim currLon as string
Set MasterSheet = Sheets(2)
Set PasteSheet = Sheets(1)

For Each cell In PasteSheet.Range("D2:D970")

    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Or cell.Value = 0 Then
        currLat=cell.offset(0,1).value
        currLon=cell.offset(0,2).value
        cell.value=evaluate("=index(Sheet2!B1:B99929,match(" & currLat&currLon & ",Sheet2!C1:C99929&Sheet2!D1:D99920,0))")
    end if
next

End Sub
```